# Find All Files in Folder Shared With Me Google Drive API v3

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am writing a .NET C# program to use files from a Google Drive.

I have a few folders shared with me. Within one of those folders are a few files that I need to use in my application.

I can get the shared directory OK:

```
// Get a list of files in the Share with me folder
var request = CurrentGDriveService.Files.List();
request.Q = "(sharedWithMe = true)";
request.Fields = "*";
var results = request.Execute();
```

**results.Files** only shows the shared folders, and none of the files below those folders.

Although I cannot see the files in the folders via the Drive api, when I log in through Google Drive via a browser, I have full access to those files.

Other code in case it is helpful...

**Authentication**

```
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Interface";

using (var stream =
       new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    string TokenCredentialsFullPath = "token.json";
    credentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(TokenCredentialsFullPath, true)).Result;
  }
```

**Connection to Service:**

```
// Create Drive API service.
CurrentGDriveService = new DriveService(new 
     BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
         HttpClientInitializer = usrCredentials,
         ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Treat the response like an IList

```cs
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.PageSize = 10;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
listRequest.Corpora = "allDrives";
listRequest.Q = "sharedWithMe = true"; // not in brackets!

// List files.
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

foreach (var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
}
```

This prints out 10 files that are shared with you and their id.

#### Reference

- [ListRequest](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest.html)

Comment: No, this does not work either. I thought the: listRequest.Corpora = "allDrives"; was going to do it, but I still only get the directories, and not the files in the directories.

Comment: Incidentally, in addition to the Corpora setting, I had to also include:             listRequest.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;
            listRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;

Comment: What result do you get from the console for this?

Comment: Just the three directories. However, I recently ran code that put a folder in the directory, and uploaded  3 files to that directory. All of those files show. So, it makes me wonder: if a Folder is shared with me, but not the files within the folder, what am I supposed to see? I see them all when I browse through the DRIVE web app.

Comment: Is it possible that you are the owner of these files within the shared folder, or that they have some different permissions? Usually they inherit permissions from the folder but can be overridden. If you do a simple GET request for one of these files and check the permissions, what can you see?

Comment: If I can see the files when I use the GDRIVE browser application, doesn't that imply that I have permissions on the files via the API?

Comment: You'd think so but for whatever reason they may not be "shared with me" permissions. As I said, the permissions are inherited but can be overridden. Maybe you are the owner of these files within shared drive or something. Its probable that something odd is up with these files since you say the code is working fine. Have you tried the API explorer to contrast? (side bar on this URL https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) just to be 100% sure its not the API but the actual files.

Comment: I haven't. But I will and report back.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue I had before. Must gave been something odd about those files. They were created to test, so maybe something got crossed. I'll accept this as the answer for now. One question tho: Why no braces around 'shared with me = true'? What difference would it make?

Comment: Ok, glad to hear. To be honest with you I have never tested it without the braces, so it is possible that it works. I can tell you for sure that it works without braces though, it depends on how the library deals with it. Maybe its sensitive to braces, maybe not.